# Making a POST HttpRequest (XMLHttpRequest) in Dart

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, httprequest, dart

I try to submit a simple POST HttpRequest in Dart.
According to the docs, the method should be `request.onLoad.add` instead of `request.onLoad.listen`, which is the one I am using. Yet I arrived here because `onLoad.add' did not exist. :O
The issue: No errors, no submit, no success message.

```
void main() {
  query("#sample_text_id")
    ..text = "Click me!"
    ..onClick.listen(submitHttpRequest('test.php'));
}

void submitHttpRequest(String phpFile, [json, callback(int status)]) {
  print('yeeep');
  var request = new HttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', 'php/$phpFile');
  request.onLoad.listen((event) { print('event'); }, onDone: ()
   {
      print('loaded');
      handleResponse(request.status);
      if(callback != null) {
        callback(request.status);
      }
   }, onError: (e) { print('err' + e.toString()); });


}
```

The output is

```
Invalid CSS property name: -webkit-touch-callout
yeeep
```

I have no idea where the first line comes from, I am pretty sure that was generated and none of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc on the default [HttpRequest](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/HttpRequest.html) constructor seems outdated.

To make it work :

- you have to add `request.send();` at the end of `submitHttpRequest` to send the request.
- fix the way you add your listener on click. In your original code you add the result of `submitHttpRequest('test.php')` (that is `null`) to `..onClick.listen()`. You should have done : `..onClick.listen((_) => submitHttpRequest('test.php'))`.

Here's the working version :

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  query("#sample_text_id")
    ..text = "Click me!"
    ..onClick.listen((_) => submitHttpRequest('test.php'));
}

void submitHttpRequest(String phpFile, [json, callback(int status)]) {
  print('yeeep');
  var request = new HttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', 'php/$phpFile');
  request.onLoad.listen((event) { print('event'); }, onDone: () {
    print('loaded');
    handleResponse(request.status);
    if(callback != null) {
      callback(request.status);
    }
  }, onError: (e) { print('err' + e.toString()); });
  request.send(json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the request as the last step:

```
request.send();
```

I usually prefer to use the following simpler method:

```
HttpRequest.getString(URL)
.then((stringResponse) { print("loaded"); } )
.catchError((error) { print("error: $error"); } );
```

Comment: Too bad it doesn't have as many properties as the original instantiated object to retrieve status codes from, etc :(